# What does "me gusta" mean in these sentences?

Tags: significado, locuciones

What does "me gusta" mean in these sentences?

> En un primer momento, las firmas no se fijaban tanto en la cantidad de
>   seguidores ***o me gusta*** que suscitaba su cuenta. Si tiene una tasa
>   alta de interacción con el contenido [o engagement, como se conoce
>   entre los especialistas], de comentarios ***y me gustas***, el valor se
>   acerca a los 750 euros.

This is extracted from this news in a Spanish newspaper: [¿Se puede hacer caja con Instagram?](http://economia.elpais.com/economia/2016/08/10/actualidad/1470816799_437694.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It refers to 'likes' in social networks, such as Facebook likes and so. In the Spanish version of Facebook, when you see the 'like it' button, it says 'me gusta', and that's the reason why 'me gusta' is used as a sustantive there.